# How much theory should be given in article?

Tags: publications, writing, theory, chemistry

I have created a software and the assisting methodology for its application to some kinetic studies. I used a lot of theory. E.g., I used kinetic model, reactor model, data analysis (about 7 methods to analyse the results totally). Now I have prepared an article where I report this methodology and demonstrate the results of its application.

***How much theory should I include into the article?*** Can I only refer to other publications/books for the models/methods proposed earlier?

I have seen many publications where a part of theory is taken out from the main text to appendices ([example with 5 appendices](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0006349505730939)). In some journals appendices are not included into the article (supplementary, accessible online-only). Is it a good solution to include some theory in appendices? If yes, how many appendices would be OK (i.e., would the reader like the article with 7 appendices? As for me, I do not have anything against many appendices).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "thoery", "kinetic studies" and most of the other keywords in your question. It sounds like the answer might be very specific to whatever field your research is in. If there's a Stack Exchange site for that subject, that might be a better place to ask than here. (In that case, please click the "flag" button below the post annd ask the moderators to move your question. Don't just copy-paste it to another site.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides the already given hints I offer another guideline:

**Give as many background as you yourself would have needed to get the idea and method before you have developed it.**

In other words:

**Write the paper to your former self (before you knew about what you've found out).**

If you would have been happy with a paper that described the idea and references a lot to standard, readily available books for the background, then go for that style. If you had found it awkward to work through a paper that has a lot of references to papers/books that are hard to find, then don't do that. Note that different principles can apply at different places in the same paper.

These hint is in some way a simplified form of the general hint

**Know your audience!**

Oh, and also discuss this with your advisor.

Answer (score 2):

My usual approach is based on two main ideas:

- One new idea per paper
- Each paper must be self-contained

So, if I create a new methodology for something that can be applied to something else, that's two papers, one theoretical, one application. Of course, that's computer science, not sure how it translates to your field.

The second is more important to the question. IMHO, you should include enough definitions so the reader can understand most of the paper without external sources, but not too much. You cannot waste space with derivations that are not your original work (unless you are writing a textbook). Explain the very basic, go straight to the end results, provide the references for further information.

Keep the focus on your contribution and make sure that it is very clear to the reader what is your contribution and what is not.

Comment: I forgot to say, it also depends on the length of the article. If it is a short article, I often just give the reference and nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

If you refer to **theory** as **derivation**, then it is fine to refer to older/relative publications and only add the equations (in the manuscript) you have derived or those that are not included in previous studies. You do not have to derive/write every single equation! If the derivation is way too long, you can add the complete derivation (if needed?!) in an appendix. Or even, write two papers! One on the **derivation**, **approach** or **theory** itself and one on the application of such approach.

If you refer to **derivation** as solved examples, then you can always add a complete example in the appendix. The length of such appendix will largely depend on the journal's rules.